# C# COM server code reuse strategy

Tags: c#, com

In my project I need to create several com servers that implements one interface. Com servers will be created by different programmers. There are too many identical parts in COM modules like input xml parsing, log, etc. What is the best way to reuse maximum of identical source code between this projects?

Can we create COM server class as closed class with delegates for specified com server operations? How to reuse it without copy-paste? How to change guid and progid for this class in each project?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add the common parts to a hierachy of abstract base classes. Then derive the COM server classes from these base classes. If one base class is enough then go for one instead of a hierarchy. The CLSIDs should be specified on the concrete classes (the COM server classes).